# efficient, pythonic way to zig-zag through meshgrid data

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to make a trajectory of (x, y) points that zig-zag through an even grid. I want to be able to specify which axis to start on. Is there an efficient way to do this with numpy?

For instance:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5])
```

produces

```
xv: [[1 2 3]
     [1 2 3]]
yv: [[4 4 4]
     [5 5 5]]
```

I want my trajectory to be:

```
(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (3,5), (2,5), (1,5)
```

or

```
(1,4), (1,5), (2,5), (2,4), (3,4), (3,5)
```

Comment: what have you tried? I would assume maybe something with zip or defining your own function??

Comment: What about `np.dstack(np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5]))`?

Comment: I've tried duplicating the xv, yv arrays, flipping along the appropriate axis, and awkwardly recombining the arrays, then reshaping into a 1D trajectory:
xv_merge = [[1 2 3]
                     [3 2 1]]

Comment: @Kasramvd: I just poked at np.dstack which merges the two sets of coordinates, but doesn't seem to apply the every-other flip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can avoid creating the heavy meshgrids by directly working on the `1D` arrays as a performance measure with `array-initialization` for the two output arrays and then broadcasted assignments for assigning the input arrays once as they are along the even-numbered places and flipped along the odd numbered ones. This gives us the zig-zag ordering.

The implementation would be -

```
def create_zigzag_grids(a,b):
    m,n = len(b), len(a)

    out1 = np.empty((m,n,2),dtype=int)
    out1[:,:,1] = b[:,None]
    out1[::2,:,0] = a
    out1[1::2,:,0] = a[::-1]

    out2 = np.empty((n,m,2),dtype=int)
    out2[:,:,0] = a[:,None]
    out2[::2,:,1] = b
    out2[1::2,:,1] = b[::-1]
    return out1.reshape(-1,2), out2.reshape(-1,2)
```

Sample run -

1) Input and output :

```
In [748]: a,b = np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([5,6,7])
     ...: out1, out2 = create_zigzag_grids(a,b)
     ...:
```

2) Create meshgrid to verify our results :

```
In [749]: xv, yv = np.meshgrid(a,b)

In [750]: xv
Out[750]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [751]: yv
Out[751]: 
array([[5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7]])
```

3) Verify results :

```
In [752]: out1
Out[752]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [3, 6],
       [2, 6],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 7],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 7]])

In [753]: out2
Out[753]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 7],
       [2, 7],
       [2, 6],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [3, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 7],
       [4, 6],
       [4, 5]])
```

**Runtime test**

Other approach(es) -

```
def Psidom(a,b): # @Psidom's stack based soln
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    xv[1::2] = xv[1::2,::-1]
    out1 = np.stack((xv, yv), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)
    yv[:,1::2] = yv[::-1, 1::2]
    out2 = np.stack((xv.T, yv.T), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)
    return out1, out2
```

Timings -

```
In [829]: a = np.arange(100)
     ...: b = np.arange(100)+100

In [830]: %timeit Psidom(a,b)
     ...: %timeit create_zigzag_grids(a,b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.1 µs per loop

In [831]: a = np.arange(1000)
     ...: b = np.arange(1000)+1000

In [832]: %timeit Psidom(a,b)
     ...: %timeit create_zigzag_grids(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

You might flip the coordinate every other row by using:

```
xv[1::2] = xv[1::2,::-1]
```

Then stack `xv` and `yv`.

---

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5])
xv[1::2] = xv[1::2,::-1]

xv
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [3, 2, 1]])

np.stack((xv, yv), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)

#array([[1, 4],
#       [2, 4],
#       [3, 4],
#       [3, 5],
#       [2, 5],
#       [1, 5]])
```

Or flip `yv`:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5])
yv[:,1::2] = yv[::-1, 1::2]

yv
#array([[4, 5, 4],
#       [5, 4, 5]])

np.stack((xv.T, yv.T), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)
#array([[1, 4],
#       [1, 5],
#       [2, 5],
#       [2, 4],
#       [3, 4],
#       [3, 5]])
```

Comment: Or `xv[1::2]=xv[1::2,::-1] , dstack((xv,yv)).reshape(-1,2)`

Comment: @B.M. Yes. I have been silly using two step indexing.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom and B.M.: that's what I was looking for